# Howto Set Attribute Programatically in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Below android XML code does add password box to **Show Password** button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

...
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/layout_email"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorHint"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled = "true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/colorHint"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_android_white_18dp">
```

What I'm plannig is to write a `NativeRenderer` for `Entry`(password) that have **ShowPassword** button. For that reason I need to set `passwordToggleEnabled` for `TextInputLayout` that does not have such kind of property. How can I add `android:textColorHint` attribute in my view's `AttributeSet` programatically?

Comment: Are you using XForms? I assume so as you mentioned custom renderer. Please confirm

Comment: Yes, Xamarin.Forms

Comment: do you have sample project you can share so I don't have to recreate your code including renderer? Then I cam make modifications on it